# Can a US visa refusal make entry in Schengen difficult?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, brazilian-citizens

I'm planing a trip to the following cities later this year:

Dublin, London, Brussels, Amsterdam and Munich.

I'm Brazilian, and in 2015 my US visa application was refused. They said that I did not prove that I would return to my country.

Since Brazilians don't need a Schengen visa to enter most of Europe, I guess there'll be an interview when I arrive at the airport.

Should I worry that things may get difficult because of the US visa refusal three years ago?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. They won't even know about it let alone ask you.

Comment: Even if short, this is a very accurate summary of the situation. +1

Comment: @o.m. Read again. The OP doesn't need a visa for schengen. The bar for refusing entry at the border is much higher than refusing a visa (even if it's not on paper).

Comment: @greatone, yes, deleting.